# Can't get a web app to work offline on iPod

Tags: jquery, html, web-applications

I've written a basic password manager type web application to run offline on a mobile device (testing on a 4th gen iPod Touch). I've added the app to the Home Screen and it all works fine while the iPod is online and can reach the server. Once I put the iPod offline, when I open the app the following dialog comes up:

> Cannot Open PwdThing
>
> PwdThing could not be opened because it is not connected to the Internet

The single static HTML file for the app (`passwordthing.html`) points to the manifest file:

```
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
...
```

The `cache.manifest` file includes all the files used by the app (including the [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) files):

```
CACHE MANIFEST
passwordthing.html
passwordthing.js
...
```

And the `cache.manifest` file is set up to be served as `text/cache-manifest` in the `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
```

All the source files are on [Github](https://github.com/belfryimages/PasswordThing) ([this commit](https://github.com/belfryimages/PasswordThing/commit/3d850d7b718493ffb2271bc416f423583016dbc9) is the version at the time of writing) and I have set up a [public server](http://passwordthing.belfryimages.com.au/passwordthing.html) to install it from as well.

Why can't I get my app to work offline?

Comment: you should point chrome at your app to see if you are getting any caching errors.

Comment: @hvgotcodes I just found the caching error (bad filename), if you can add a new answer per your comment I'll accept it :-)

Comment: done -- you still might want always change your manifest name with every release.  Otherwise, a file might change, but the name stays the same, and it wont get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that you have not changed the file, and mobile safari has cached an old version of the manifest.  add a comment to your manifest.  You might also want to try changing the name of the manifest file itself; I have had to do that to get my IPad to cache -- everytime I update my application I change the name of the manifest to include the date.

Note that iOS4.2 has much better manifest support.  You might see things improve when it is out.

Edit -- Or, as it turns out, its just a bad file name. ;) (see comments on question).

Comment: Thanks, tried changing the manifest filename but no difference :-(

Comment: @ben did you try loading your app in chrome and looking at the console?

Answer (score 1):

[[Replicated [my answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361948/offline-ios-web-app-loads-my-manifest-but-doesnt-work-offline/4362029#4362029) below because it may apply here to:]]

I found debugging HTML5 offline apps to be a pain.  I found the code from this article helped me figure out what was wrong with my app:

http://jonathanstark.com/blog/2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/

> Debugging HTML 5 Offline Application Cache
>   by Jonathan Stark
>
> If you are looking to provide offline access to your web app, the Offline Application Cache available in HTML5 is killer. However, it’s a giant PITA to debug, especially if you’re still trying to get your head around it.
>
> If you are struggling with the cache manifest, add the following JavaScript to your main HTML page and view the output in the console using Firebug in Firefox or Debug > Show Error Console in Safari.
>
> If you have any questions, PLMK in the comments.
>
> HTH,
>   j

```
var cacheStatusValues = [];
cacheStatusValues[0] = 'uncached';
cacheStatusValues[1] = 'idle';
cacheStatusValues[2] = 'checking';
cacheStatusValues[3] = 'downloading';
cacheStatusValues[4] = 'updateready';
cacheStatusValues[5] = 'obsolete';

var cache = window.applicationCache;
cache.addEventListener('cached', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('checking', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('downloading', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('error', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('noupdate', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('obsolete', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('progress', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('updateready', logEvent, false);

function logEvent(e) {
    var online, status, type, message;
    online = (navigator.onLine) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    status = cacheStatusValues[cache.status];
    type = e.type;
    message = 'online: ' + online;
    message+= ', event: ' + type;
    message+= ', status: ' + status;
    if (type == 'error' && navigator.onLine) {
        message+= ' (prolly a syntax error in manifest)';
    }
    console.log(message);
}

window.applicationCache.addEventListener(
    'updateready',
    function(){
        window.applicationCache.swapCache();
        console.log('swap cache has been called');
    },
    false
);

setInterval(function(){cache.update()}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure the cache.manifest has the correct BOM (in my case UTF-8) that matches your  in the HTML file. If you just have a non-BOM ASCII file, and the Content Type is set to UTF-8, the caching will fail

HTH someone.

Christine Boersen